# Why output of second program differs from first program?

Tags: c++

When returning a reference to the object on which the function is invoked, the returned reference can be used to chain function calls on a single object.

Here, I am applying the same concept. But I am getting different output if I initialize objects differently.

First example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1(5, 5);

  // Chained function calls.  All calls modify the same object
  // as the same object is returned by reference
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);

  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Output is 10 and 20, which is correct.

However, output is not correct for the second example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Output is 10 and 0.

Why? I think both are the same, the output of the second program should be 10 and 20 too. What is the reason it's different?

Comment: You tagged this C# but your code appears to be C++, which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the second version of your program returns by value. This means that the second call (i.e. `setY`) is performed on a *copy* of `obj1`, not on the `obj1` itself. That's why only `X` ends up being set, but not `Y`.

In your first program, on the other hand, the setters return their results as a reference. This means that no copy is being made, so `setY` is called on the same object as `setX`, not on its copy.

Comment: then Why its setting **x** only why not **y** also

Comment: @vivekjain Because the initial call (i.e. `setX`) is done on the object itself, before the setter gets to make a copy (implicitly, through returning by value).